# How fast might technical knowledge & culture spread in the pre-colonial Americas?

Tags: travel, trade

Unbeknownst to the majority of the continent, there is an alien invasion in progress. Finger-sized and not particularly threatening, they've been confined to the coasts of North America by the unique challenges they face in being so diminutive. Like any good alien invaders, they possess advanced technology and an exotic culture that has fascinated some of the people who happen to live or travel near them. Not so burdened, these artifacts and ideas precede their creators, destined for every corner of the world.

The only question is: how quickly?

**Problem Statement:**

Assuming the Algonquin tribes along the east coast of North America have acquired some technical knowledge (scientific thought, science books, building methods) and small, civilian devices built-to-scale (radios, primarily) from the miniature European colonists, how long would it take for them to spread across the continent? Major checkpoints include: the plains, west coast, and the city of Tenochtitlan.

Since this can be considered a very open question, answers should involve examples from history. Arguments involving the spread of real colonial technology are best, but others taken from the history of the Old World are welcome, too.

**Assumptions:**

- The state of the Americas is almost identical to that of their real, pre-Columbian counterpart.
- The culture of the colonists is recognizable, although distorted by the circumstances of this world.
- Disease, foreign and domestic, has not plagued the continent in recent memory; there is no [smallpox apocalypse](https://www.pbs.org/gunsgermssteel/variables/smallpox.html) in this timeline.
- The indigenous have not acquired transportation technology from the colonists.
- There is no agenda to propagate the technology by either the colonists or the east coast tribes beyond what the latter would be naturally incentivized to do by e.g. trade profits.
- There is a small but steady flow of trade between only a few east coast tribes and the few separatist (or slightly rebellious) colonies. Generally, there is little interaction between the two groups.
- While the tribes have possession of technical knowledge and devices, please assume that this has not significantly altered their way of life; for the majority of my timeline, this is true due to a number of conspiring circumstances.
- The colonists possess infinite energy, "anti-gravity" devices, and advanced robotics (think frostpunk), but beyond that are no more advanced than we are.

Comment: This question was surprisingly difficult to tag. Are there any suggestions for other, relevant, tags given I am interested in arguments with some historical basis?

Comment: This question could have many different answers depending on how the technology is received by tribes along it's journey. It might be easier if you came up with an educated guess about the rate of transfer and asked us to do a reality check on that.

Comment: You might look at the spread of a couple of actual technologies, horsemanship and firearms.  The Plains cultures readily adopted the horse, and became equal to the Europeans, if not superior, in its use.  But horses make more horses.  They also readily adopted firearms, but were AFAIK entirely dependent on trade to acquire them and their ammunition.

Comment: What year is it, approximately?

Comment: @Willk To the indigenous, it is the 16th Century - history beyond that requires inference given the interference by colonists in real life. To Europe, it is the 21st C., and the colonists live to a standard commensurate with the 20th C. By the way, what edits did you make to the question? I couldn't spot the difference. EDIT: I misspelt precede, didn't I? Good catch.

Comment: *"The state of the Americas is almost identical to that of their real, pre-Columbian counterpart"* . . . except of course that it isn't. In the actual pre-Columbian North American there was no civilization in possession of a scientific corpus or exotic devices and building methods. Simply introducing such a culture would change history so much as to make it unrecognizable. (And, a pet peeve. If there is culture which is truely in possession of a modern-ish scientific corpus then *that culture must certainly have millions of people*, and the contact must have happened centuries ago.)

Comment: BTW, the question in the title is trivial -- the technical knowledge etc. will spread at the speed of plot. Obviously.

Comment: @AlexP Please read the question again; these are finger-sized colonists from Europe that have been unsuccessful in their expansionary efforts. They are confined to a sliver of a portion of the entire Americas, and are "not particularly threatening" - i.e. a non-entity that most (of the few) tribes in the area ignore. The loyal (implied majority) colonies don't even trade with the indigenous that *are* there! Please give the benefit of the doubt that I have engineered circumstances such that their presence is negligible, or at least ask meaningful questions so I can prove this to you.

Comment: I don't mean the colonists. I mean the *"tribes along the east coast of North America have acquired technical knowledge (scientific corpus, building methods)"*. I doesn't matter from where they acquired it. If they truly are in possesion of a modern-ish scientific corpus, then: (1) they number in the millions, or else they don't really have a scientific corpus; (2) they needed *centuries* to master the scientific corpus and the technology; and (3) their presence would change history beyond all recognition. (Millions because there are only so many people who have the capacity to learn and use.)

Comment: @AlexP Ah, that makes a lot more sense. Scientific corpus appears to have been the wrong choice of words - at most the east coast tribes might have a stack of books (hence use of corpus) and the handful of curious individuals who transcribed and studied them. The tribes themselves remain largely unchanged, although the degree varies significantly between them due to cultural inertia, proximity to separatist colonies, logistical lead time, political events, etc. I will clarify this in my question.

Comment: It depends how useful the technology is to others, especially for the purpose of warfare. An interesting tidbit I recall from one history lecture is that the invention of stirrups for horse-riding spread very quickly, because they greatly increased the viability of using horses in battle.

Comment: Actually the first major checkpoint are the Appalachian mountains. Those present a serious trade barrier. That is why the east coast tribes were significantly different from the Ohio culture.

Comment: Where on the coast this invasion happens will make a difference. Invading Maine will have a very different effect than invading the Florida panhandle or Texas coast. Down south, one technology that would make a significant difference would be disease prevention. The result would be a population increase that would drive warfare to take over more space. It would run into the Mississippian culture. We don't know enough about that culture to know how it would react.

Comment: @DavidR Swamps are not fun when you're tiny, and the south is hit the worst by storms AIUI. Therefore I imagine the majority of the colonies would be located roughly along the coasts that the Algonquin cultures settled. Don't worry too much about the unknowns - obviously the variability means that we can't reasonably expect a precise answer. Just stating the order of magnitude (decades, centuries, millennia) going by things like metalworking and the average mechanism for knowledge transfer (looks to be conquest?) would be deeply useful.

Answer (score 1):

Well, how fast *did* technology spread?  The [Clovis Point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clovis_point) in particular, swept over the continent which confused archeologists for a long time since it changed their *stuff* but did not actually replace the people living there.

I've not seen any actual numbers for how fast this was, only the implication that it was instant in archeological terms.  So, faster than cities grow and change.  The tech lasted about 600 years, so the initial spread must have been *much* shorter than that; like within one or two generations.

Comment: Impressive. If I'm reading http://pidba.utk.edu/maps.htm right, they even made it into Mesoamerica. This is definitely worth looking into, although it's so early in history that it may not be not be applicable to the situation of the 15th century with its large, organized and sometimes sedentary cultures.

Comment: In 15th century, you had people travelling rapidly across the continent.  It's the _idea_ that spreads, not the people.  How long did it take modern people to switch to smart phones?  The question is, why would the villagers _not_ adopt the new tech, and would that hold-out last more than a generation?

Comment: @JDługosz Technology that requires significant resources won't spread rapidly. This invasion team is likely to lose a lot of technology that needs a huge supply chain. Technology that can be built out of local materials is an idea that can spread rapidly. Technology that can't spread rapidly is tech that requires major changes to lifestyle. Thus, growing corn took a while to spread from Mexico to the Ohio valley and likely required population replacement.